# how to fix opencv video freeze few second when sound play?

Tags: python

i try create application motion detector, when detected will play alarm. the program is running but the problem is when sound play video will freeze few second. so how to fix that?
I was tired of looking for references, but couldn't find anything.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from playsound import playsound

# Video Capture 
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(50, 200, True)

# frame
frameCount = 0

while(1):
    # frame value
    ret, frame = capture.read()

    # cek frame
    if not ret:
        break

    frameCount += 1
    # resize frame
    resizedFrame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.50, fy=0.50)

    # foreground
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(resizedFrame)

    # jumlah Pixel
    count = np.count_nonzero(fgmask)

    if (frameCount > 1 and count > 5000):
        playsound('tune.mp3')

    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print('Frame: %d, Pixel Count: %d' % (frameCount, count))

    cv2.imshow('Frame', resizedFrame)
    cv2.imshow('Mask', fgmask)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k == 27:
        break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `opencv` when You play a sound from `playsound`. Even if You try calling `plahsound using threads` it will still freeze.

However, You can use `Pygame's Mixer`, which doesn't interrupt opencv's window. You can play a sound by:

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
sound = mixer.Sound('mysound.ogg')
sound.play()
```

**However, I think Pygame's mixer is incompatible with mp3 files.** You might wanna use .wav instead, or convert your mp3 file to .ogg format.